# How do I test a range in KDB?

Tags: kdb

Let's say I have a range `3 < x < 5`.

What's the cleanest way to get `1` if `x > 5`, `-1` if `x < 3` and `0` if it's in the range `3 <x <5`?

I'm trying to mix together `&` and `|` (trying to adapt the answer from here: [In KDB/Q, how do I clip numbers to be in the range -1, 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68441176/in-kdb-q-how-do-i-clip-numbers-to-be-in-the-range-1-1)). I'm not sure if it's possible this way though.

Comment: Are you looking for numbers outside (a) `3<x<5` or (b) `3<=x<=5` range?

Comment: Either, I can adapt the function as necessary. Your solution is good, but lacks the -1 for x < 3. I didn’t know about within though, that’s useful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option:

```
q){$[x<3;-1;x>5;1;0]}each til 10
-1 -1 -1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You could adapt the `bin` keyword which does something like what you're looking for out of the box:

```
q)3 5 bin 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
-1 -1 -1 0 0 1 1
```

If you are looking for `0` to be returned for n where `x < n < y` then I think you may be able to do something like:

```
q)f:{[range;x] (range + 1 0) bin x}
q)range35:f[3 5;]
q)range35 0N!til 10
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

Which returns a 0 for the number 4

Answer (score 3):

You could look at a [step dictionary](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/apply/#step-dictionaries) which can be used in many places:

```
q)(`s#-0W 3 6!-1 0 1) til 10
-1 -1 -1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Or fill the base case:

```
q)-1^(`s#3 6!0 1) til 10
-1 -1 -1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Even better here for your exact question is to go direct to using [bin](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/bin/):

```
q)3 6 bin til 10
-1 -1 -1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As an aside Sean and Rian's answers using `bin` are faster than using conditional evaluation - however in this context its already "fast". For readability's sake I would select the conditional evaluation due to how clear and easy it is to read, understand and modify the conditions and returns.

```
q)\t:10000 {[range;x] (range + 1 0) bin x}[3 5;-50+til 100]
11
q)\t:10000 3 6 bin -50+til 100
10
q)\t:10000 {$[x<3;-1;x>5;1;0]}'[-50+til 100]
75
```